# Deriving tangent plane equation from scalar equation of plane

Tags: multivariable-calculus, plane-curves

There's one step in the derivation that I don't understand. I'll explain some of the derivation and then explain which step I don't understand.

1. Begin with scalar equation of plane:

   A(x-x<sub>0</sub>) + B(y-y<sub>o</sub>) + C(z-z<sub>o</sub>) = 0
2. Divide this equation by C and

   let a = -A/C and

   let b = -B/C
3. It can now be written as:

   z-z<sub>o</sub> = a(x-x<sub>o</sub>) + b(y-y<sub>o</sub>)
4. The intersection of this equation with the plane y = y<sub>o</sub> is:

   z-z<sub>o</sub> = a(x-x<sub>o</sub>),

   which is recognized as the equation of a line with slope a.

The rest of the derivation is irrelevant. I don't understand how, in step 2, letting a = -A/C makes the variable 'a' the slope of a line in the xz-plane. A and C are defined in the scalar equation of a plane, respectively, as the x and z component of a vector that's orthogonal to the plane that its equation defines.

It appears to say that dividing the x by the z component defines the slope of a line in the xz-plane, but shouldn't it be dividing the z by the x component for that to be true?
Right now it seems equivalent as to defining the slope in the xy-plane as x/y, but we all know it is actually y/x. This is what I'm confused about.

Oh my! I think I might understand it now. since C/A is the slope of the line ORTHOGONAL to the line in the tangent plane in the xz-plane, then to find the slope of the line in the tangent plane, it takes the negative reciprocal of C/A to get -A/C!

If you understand this question, could you verify that this is the correct explanation for letting a = -A/C?

Comment: Yes, it is the correct explanation.

Answer (score 0):

In general the slope of a line $y=mx$ is $m$. For example, if you plug $x=1$ into it, you get $y=m$. This $\frac{y}{x}=\frac{m}{1}=m$ is what you meant by $\frac{y}{x}$.